# Opening Tkinter Color Chooser Without Button

Tags: python, tkinter, colors, jcolorchooser

Python: I need to use a color chooser for my coding class right now. However, the button is making it super difficult to incorporate in my code. Is there anyway to open a color chooser without a button in Python? I need to set a variable equal to the color choosers position. This is my code as of now.

Comment: what code? you haven't added any. and also what event should trigger the opening of the color chooser?

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure how you want to call `askcolor()` without button or any other widget.

I would suggest simple solution, when command of the button is bound to function which calls `askcolour()` dialog and assignes colour to variable if value is choosen.

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Canvas
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
    
class AskColor:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.master = master
        self.colour = (None,None)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text='Colour', command=self.button_command)
        self.indicator_creation()
        self.button.pack()

    def indicator_creation(self):

        self.indicator = Canvas(self.master)
        self.oval = self.indicator.create_oval(50, 50, 100, 100)
        self.indicator.itemconfig(self.oval, fill=self.colour[1])
        self.indicator.pack()

    def button_command(self):

        chosen_colour = askcolor()
        if chosen_colour != (None,None):
            self.colour = chosen_colour
        self.indicator.itemconfig(self.oval,fill=self.colour[1])
if __name__ == '__main__':

    window = Tk()
    AskColor(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

[After colour selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYtV4.png)

[Before colour selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gjOj.png)

Comment: @Matiiss Canvas here is just to illustrate results. (unnecessery for functioning code)